# Python For Loop errors on sedond Pass

Tags: python

I am trying to use a for loop as follows:

```
addresses = [0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33]

for address in addresses:
   print(address)
   chirp = chirp.Chirp(address=address,
                       read_moist=True,
                       read_temp=True,
                       read_light=True,
                       min_moist=False,
                       max_moist=False,
                       temp_scale='farenheit',
                       temp_offset=0)
   chirp.trigger()
   log_values(address, chirp.moist, chirp.temp, chirp.light)
   time.sleep(1)
```

It seems to work on the first pass in the console I see 48, then 49 then get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "readings_logger.py", line 17, in <module>
chirp = chirp.Chirp(address=address,
AttributeError: 'Chirp' object has no attribute 'Chirp'
```

Which I think indicates that it ran once.  Then on the second pass could not run it.  My first thought was a local variable issue so tried to delete 'chirp' lower case 'c' but that did not help.  My guess is this threading but I am new to python and not sure how to prevent that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are reassigning chirp when you are setting it equal to `chirp.Chirp(...)`.

Try to change the variable assignment (after `print(address)` to something like `loop_chirp = chirp.Chirp(...)`. Each subsequent line would now be changed to `loop_chirp` followed by the attribute.

Comment: This worked well!  Have to wait 6 mins to accept your answer!